# Everything is Pink

Tags: animation, uv

I moved my Blender files into a new folder, to help clean up my directory, but my textures went pink. I remember this happened before to me, but I can't remember how I fixed this. How do I designate in Blender the new locations of these files on my HD. Does anybody know how to help me? Thanks!

Comment: Try `File > External Data > Find Missing Files`. It will let you pick the directory where your textures are.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem!